# U-Boot : boot without reloading DTB

Tags: boot, u-boot, device-tree

I'm using U-Boot on a Raspberry Pi Compute Module. The boot process is :
RPi firmware --> U-Boot --> Linux

I'm setting up some things about devices in the config.txt, that is used by the RPi firmware. But when I re-load the DTB with U-Boot, it actually erase the settings done by the RPi firmware, and some devices won't work in Linux.

I boot using the ***bootz*** command, and I can't use it without giving it a DTB, or it will crash at booting Linux ...

Do you guys have an idea of how I can boot without reloading a fresh DTB ?

Answer (score 0):

This is still something under active development and discussion.  At this point in time it is likely that https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/693631/ and https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/693632/ will be applied to mainline U-Boot for the next (v2017.01) release.  You may wish to apply these locally, test, and if they work reply to the list with your Tested-by tag.  Thanks!